# How to increase root allocation, when next partition is /home Ubuntu18.04

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted

[image]

I got a notification saying "Low free space in root" 
How should I increase the size of / without losing any data.

Comment: Have you housecleaned? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace Do you have good backups? And partition change has risks, and powerfailure during change will corrupt system to where re-install and restore is about only choice. Your sda4 is over full. NTFS likes 30% free to work well. At 10% free, your defrag will take forever (your are defagging NTFS?) & running chkdsk? You could delete swap and move /. I typically do not like moving / left as higher risk, but it should work. Then recreate swap where you have room. Note you must update fstab with new UUID, before booting.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) Archive your /dev/sda4 NTFS partition data somewhere else, delete /dev/sda4, resize your Extended /dev/sda3 to take up all empty space, move your /home (/dev/sda7) to the back, and finally resize your root /dev/sda6 as needed. Do not move root /dev/sda6, only resize it from its end boundaries.

2) Shrink your /home (/dev/sda7), then resize root /dev/sda6 from its end boundaries.

Better use a live CD to do either.